# AWS Kinesis object has no attribute: update_shard_count

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to implement dynamic sharding in AWS Kinesis. I have created a sample python script to update the shard count in kinesis stream using Boto3 library to connect python with AWS Kinesis.
But when I use `update_shard_count` method it is giving **Kinesis object no attribute update_shard_count** error.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('kinesis',region_name='us-east-1')
response = client.update_shard_count(
    StreamName='xyzstream',
    TargetShardCount=2,
    ScalingType='UNIFORM_SCALING' )
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    AttributeError: 'Kinesis' object has no attribute
>   'update_shard_count'

Then how I can update kinesis shard count using API?

Comment: I just tried this with version 1.4.2 of boto3 and the Kinesis client object definitely has an ``update_shard_count`` method.  What version are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to upgrade your Boto3. I have Boto3 1.4.3 and I see `update_shard_count` method in Kinesis module. Next I check in a older version and do not see the method.

```
    >>> import boto3
    >>> boto3.__version__
    '1.4.3'
    >>> client = boto3.client('kinesis')
    >>> client.update_shard_count
<bound method Kinesis.update_shard_count of <botocore.client.Kinesis object at 0x7fbfb7445b90>>
```

**Old Version**

```
>>> import boto3
>>> boto3.__version__
'1.4.0'
>>> client = boto3.client('kinesis')
>>> client.update_shard_count
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>    AttributeError: 'Kinesis' object has no attribute
>   'update_shard_count'